# How does Dependabot finds CHANGELOG files to be displayed in the PR?

Tags: nuget, dependabot

I want to display the contents of a `CHANGELOG.md` file (which is included in the `nuget` package I publish) in the PR created by Dependabot.
Example of such behavior for `FluentValidation` package:
[image: Working example of Dependabot extracting CHANGELOG]

I can't figure out how to do that. Additionally, I have noticed that even for the same 'FluentValidation` package, another PR was missing the changelog:
[image]

I have not found any documentation on this topic.